# Showing the percentage value in pie chart

Tags: dc.js

```
console.log(group1.top(Infinity));
```

gives me:

```
0:
key: "M"
value: {Recovered: 122, Hospitalized: 38922, Deceased: 641, Migrated_Other: 1}
__proto__: Object
1:
key: "F"
value: {Recovered: 82, Hospitalized: 19215, Deceased:.....
```

In this code:

```
.label(function(d) {
                    return d.key+": " + (d.value[type]/<?> * 100).toFixed(2) + "%";
                })
```

if the `type` is `Recovered` then I want the sum of recovered values (122+82) in place of `<?>` i.e `d.value["Recovered"]/(122+82)`

I am just stuck at the syntax how to take the sum of values of the matched type in place of <?>.

I can only think of

```
group1.all()[0].value['Recovered']+group1.all()[1].value['Recovered']
```

Is there any better way?

**Working Code:**
https://blockbuilder.org/ninjakx/61d405cb0aaeda3be960e836f803cdd5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. One is to compute the sum, manually as you show above, or by using a [groupAll](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_groupAll) object.

The other way, which the [pie chart example](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web-src/examples/pie.html) uses, is to use the angle data saved in the pie slices:

```
// workaround for #703: not enough data is accessible through .label() to display percentages
 .on('pretransition', function(chart) {
     chart.selectAll('text.pie-slice').text(function(d) {
         return d.data.key + ' ' + dc.utils.printSingleValue((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / (2*Math.PI) * 100) + '%';
     })
 });
```

As noted, there is not enough data supplied to `.label()` to use this approach, so this is applied after drawing, using the full data objects.

Comment: This method I saw it before but I was not able to use it. Thanks for the explanations. :)
Finally I am able to build the dashboard though after adding more charts and functionalities. `post render (tooltip)` for the individual graph of stacked(third one) chart stopped working. There might be something wrong which I need to look at. But thanks through your help I was able to build the Dashboard and I learned a lot from you and your older post which was enough to solve my problems :) http://bl.ocks.org/ninjakx/raw/9ee1324250e2d0bb62eac34e147a5da3/7015e9d7bf4ee90d65b815f1cd4c0cbaf1a02fc8/

Comment: The company dropped that porting power bi charts to dc/d3 js because I was taking a lot of time. So I decided not to waste my learning and build something using the knowledge I got from you :) Have a nice day.  https://ninjakx.github.io/corona_dash/